# Wordpres REST API: How to check id if exist on url

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm using a Wordpress REST API for building a mobile app and did heavy customizing function on ( post type ) wooCommerce to be specific that makes the response time big when requesting, for example, an endpoint like this `/wp-json/wc/v3/products`

my customization is registering new fields on product post type.

**What I need is checking if is it a single record like this?**

> `/wp-json/wc/v3/products/123456`

**Or fetching all products like this?**

> `/wp-json/wc/v3/products`

My php code for register new fields:

```php
add_action('rest_api_init','get_custom_field');

function get_custom_field() {

    register_rest_field('product', 'custom_variations', array(

       'get_callback' => 'custom_variations'

       ));

    register_rest_field('product', 'components', array(

       'get_callback' => 'product_components'

    ));
}
```

Comment: It is not so clear to me what you are asking.. and also, what is your permalink structure ?

Comment: I just need to register the rest fields in the single record rest API **with id** route so here in examples `wp-json/wc/v3/product/54897`  not everywhere with post type product

Comment: Did you find anything? @heshamshawky

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter to check if there's an id provided in the url or not.

```
add_filter('rest_prepare_product', 'prepareProductData', 10, 3);

function prepareProductData($response, $post, $request)
{
  $params = $request->get_params();
  $product_id_from_url = $params["id"];
  $should_append_extra_data = !empty( $product_id_from_url);

  //append extra data only when there's an id provided.
  if($should_append_extra_data == true) {
    //append here
  }
}
```

So in this case the `$product_id_from_url` will have `123456` for `/wp-json/wc/v3/products/123456`

Request params can be used to get many other request parameters to modify responses for different situations.